# Is it a myth to wait before eating, after workout, due to Krebs Cycle?

Tags: eating-habits, post-workout

The [Krebs cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle) is a series of chemical reactions, which is used by living organisms to generate energy through the oxidization of acetate derived from carbohydrates, fats and proteins into carbon dioxide and water.

Let's not go into the details about how the Krebs cycle works. I once read somewhere (do not recall where) that waiting at least 2 hours after the workout will have some advantages.

Is this a stupid thing?

**EDIT:**

The Krebs cycle works on aerobic state. Because it needs oxygen, during a running workout, it works (I think) only running at a low intensity, because if I run faster and the intensity grew, there will be others chemical reactions.

So let's assume I have just finished a low intensity running workout and my goal is fat loss.

Will I have some advantages by waiting a certain amount of time before I eat, or will I not?

If, on the other hand, my goal is muscle gain, do I need to have the same behavior?

Comment: What kind of workout, and what advantages? Are we talking fat loss, muscle gain, performance gain? What's the goal?

Comment: edited the question...

Comment: you can`t gain muscle by doing low intensity running, or any low intensity. you will just loose muscle, especially if you wait that long to eat.

Comment: Without seeing the source of that theory or even what the perceived benefits are, we have nothing to go on.

Answer (score 2):

I read that it is actually a disadvantage to hold off eating especially after a high intensity run. Here's a [Google books link](http://books.google.com/books?id=MsgDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=runners%20world%2015%20minute%20recovery%20meal&source=bl&ots=wBuVPmSTGB&sig=tm6LycT98QJb1nxlDjjv0CrEI8w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LLMKT6rTKtKjiQfsyYmbCQ&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCQ) that features the sept 08 issue of Runners World with an article about post run recovery. (page 50)